# Alias reference variable to datacontext value in vb.net wpf

Tags: vb.net

I have a wpf form - with model/variable binding to the data context.

In order to fetch/assign a value from a different dialog to the datacontext I use the code as below:

```
CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill).Supplier = MiscControls.ContactSelection(WCFref.F_PersonsPersonType.Supplier).ID
```

simple is:

```
CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill).Supplier = 10 'example
```

There is no problem - just looking for more eligant solution to refering the same code/variable.  The variable here is `CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill)` -  this has to be used good number of times in the form.

The question is - is there a possible to create a alias/ref variable for this '`CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill)`'?

Example:
Some where I declare `Dim X as CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill)`

Then use `x.Supplier =10` etc throughout the form back end code.

**Edit:**
My current implementation/workaround for this is:

```
 Property ObjItem As Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill
        Get
            'Return CType(Me.DataContext, Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill)
            Return Me.DataContext
        End Get
        Set(value As Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill)
            Me.DataContext = value
        End Set
End Property
```

Please advice if this is perfect or is a more elegant/correct way?

Comment: Look into [Extension Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx)

Comment: @vbnet3d - I dont think that is relevant to the one I asked.

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked for, but has exactly the same result. If you create an extension method for `DataContext` that returns a type of `Models.Purchase.PurchaseBill`, it will give you what you want. Then, you could access it as `Me.DataContext.ExtensionName.Supplier` - just remember there is often more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: @vbnet3d - I have checked again, thank you for the time - but this again needs module to be defined. - it works only in modules.  This 'extension' is really a new concept for me and sure will learn more on it.  But for now I will look for any more answers that may come.  Thank you for sharing the time and knowledge.